# Can onTaskDispatched be put in queue with CloudTasksClient

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Can you use `CloudTasksClient` to create task to function queue onTaskDispatched function.

```js
export const myOnTask = onTaskDispatched<MyOnTaskModel>({
  retryConfig: {
    maxAttempts: 5,
  },
}, async (request) => {

});
```

My enqueue function

```js
  const client = new CloudTasksClient({
    port: 8123,
    servicePath: 'localhost',
    sslCreds: ChannelCredentials.createInsecure()
  });

  const task = client.createTask({
      parent: queueName,
      task: { httpRequest: { httpMethod: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:5001/firebase-dev/us-central1/myOnTask ' } },
    });
```

I am also using https://github.com/aertje/cloud-tasks-emulator to run things locally since google is missing an emulator. I could use a function instead of onTaskDispatched but it has a 9min timeout which is not good enough for me.